# Rails Bootstrap V4 alpha 3 gem install fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I get the following error when I run bundle install do I just need to install x86-mingw32 or? Any help would be really appreciated also would it be better that I just use the CDN version?

```
Could not find gem 'bootstrap (>= 4.0.0.alpha2, ~> 4.0) x86-mingw32
the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine
```

Here is my Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.1'

#Bootstrap 4 alpha 3 gem for amazing sexiness
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.0.alpha2'

#coffee script for well cofee script stuff 

gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wondering, why do you need two gem specifiers? I got the same error running it your way but then I retried using one specifier:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '>= 4.0.0.alpha2'
```

And it worked for me.

Note: You can check releases for this gem [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/releases)

Comment: I didn't know honestly that's how it was on the ruby gem website thats all, Also thanks for the help!